# Does AppFabric help with Windows Workflow Foundation development?

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, appfabric

What are the advantages of using WF 4.0 in an AppFabric environment, for ASP.NET MVC? What additional hoops do you have to jump through if you don't have AppFabric? What bad stuff does AppFabric do that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 2):

Appfabric is more of a runtime thing then a development thing. Sure it has an API you can use from your activities but for the most part it just adds managment and configuration UI to the IIS 7 manager.

Comment: Thank you. So would you say it isn't important to WF development, or does it provide significant advantages with debugging/monitoring workflow that would aid or speed up development?

Comment: Debugging not really. Monitoring yes (and noticing exceptions you might want to debug).

Comment: Thank you Maurice. I guess what I'm trying to work out is whether AppFabric is worth installing, bearing in mind we are using WF - is it reasonably invisible, or does it add a level of complication and administration?